# Ky request cancellation not working on unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, abortcontroller, ky

I'm using [Ky](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ky) to make requests. I want to cancel the request in case the component unmounts. I have this code, where I'm using `useEffect` hook to send a signal to a function and cancel the request:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ky, { HTTPError } from 'ky'

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    /**
     * Every time the StatisticalValidation instance changes retrieves its data from the backend
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        const abortController = new AbortController()

        if (props.selectedStatisticalValidation.id) {
            getStatValidationClinicalAttrs(abortController.signal)
        }

        /** On unmount aborts Ky's request */
        return () => {
            abortController.abort()
        }
    }, [props.selectedStatisticalValidation.id])

    /** Make a request. */
    const getStatValidationClinicalAttrs = (signal: AbortSignal) => {
        const searchParams = { /* ... */ }
        ky.get(url, { searchParams, timeout: 60000, signal }).then((response) => {
            response.json().then(() => {
                // ....
            }).catch((err) => {
                // ...
            })
        }).catch((err: HTTPError) => {
            // ...
        })
    }
}
```

But It's not working, the request keeps in progress even when the unmounting function is correctly executed and the signal's `aborted` prop is `true`.

**Some important considerations**:

1. I tried with `useRef` but that didn't work either.
2. If I create the `AbortController` inside the `getStatValidationClinicalAttrs()` and abort it in that function **it works, as expected**.